How to implement DMG (Game boy) cpu's register using OOP patterns/principles to max code reusability?
I-m looking to learn better use of OOP principles/patterns so I decided to start implementing at least the basics of a GB emulator (technical part is widely covered on diff sites).
So I started with an empty CPU class, then decided to try to implement the 8bit registers A,B,C,D,E,F,H,L we also have pseudo 16bit registers AF,CD and HL (seen in GB registers), I was about to use just a dictionary and make some methods to implement them but that goes against the purpose of my initial motivation.
So, I'm wondering if a Factory Pattern is suitable to implement the registers or how would you tackle this in such a way that allow me to have some flexible code to create as many registers as I need of any type (8bit, pseudo 16bits or real 16bits) as I would like the code to be re-usable for let's say another CPU emulation, this code/class will be somehow loosely couple to my CPU class (currently empty).
Please consider this more like an abstraction learning project than actually building a fully functional DMG emulator, but pursuing a DMG emulator seems quite suitable for learning and put in practice some adv OOP concepts.

Sounds like YAGNI to me. Or in other words:  tackle this problem when/if you know which other CPU you want to emulate.

Yes, it's a YAGN, but please consider the context of it, I'm aiming to practice OOP and learn to abstract things into code, not aiming to even create an actual emulator.
As of know I've switched to Chip8 emulator as is "easier" but I'm sticking to use OOP and for it, ended up having a BaseRegister abstract class, IRegister interface and a concrete Chip8Register class, I still need to do something alike for the CPU, have a RegisterSet, and aggregate a Chip8RegisterSet as a field for a concrete CPU class, well that's my plan.


I would like the code to be re-usable for let's say another CPU emulation, this code/class will be somehow loosely couple to my CPU class (currently empty).

This may be a contortion of OOP.  Registers are entwined with a CPU.  Almost nothing happens that doesn't involve a register in some way.  And there are typically many many many ways they interact.  While I appreciate the goal of learning OOP with a project, you may be having trouble implementing registers in an OOP style because they're simply not a good match for OOP.  A very important skill when it comes to paradigms like OOP is knowing when your paradigm of choice just isn't the right one.
The same goes for the register file (the collection of registers and their names).  Your loop that executes machine code is going to be intimately entwined with the registers that the opcodes operate on.
If you wanted to make OOP registers, my recommendation would be to make a register class which is Gameboy Only (don't worry about other architectures), but make it so you can add features to it.  Watchpoints are a very important tool in debugging, letting you break the execution when a value changes.  Having a "normal" register which is fast and a "debugging" register which has support for debugging features like watchpoints may be a good use of OOP.  Maybe have a third which logs out all of the changes that occur.

I was thinking (take this from someone who has no exp designing/architecting systems) of registers just as a mean to store values, 8bit values, pesudo 16bit values and optionally (allowing the code to be extensible) .
In my mind my registers related code should allow to any other code to request (create) N registers of 8bits,  N pseudo 16bits registers, and allow me to extend to request-create 16bit registers. The operations over this requested/created register objects should be implemented somewhere else.

Design the API and see if it provides any lift.  For example, how does the API for setting an 8 bit register extend to setting a register with a 16 bit value?  It's easy to add so much OO that it makes develoent harder.  And in the case of a register, it may be 20 to 30 times slower

I will try it, is not about making a fully functional GB emulator but to abstract and model with OOP, but yes maybe I should even try a simpler console-cpu, thank you appreciate your answer/comments
